# In Coq, is there a simpler tactic for introducing a disjunction and immediately destructing it?

Tags: coq, tactic

Very often, I find myself writing some tactics like these:

```
assert (delta = 1 \/ delta <> 1) as Hd by lia.
destruct Hd.
...(proceed to work with two cases)...
```

Is there a shorter way or a more idiomatic tactic that does this?

Answer (score 4):

You can destruct things in many ways at the time you introduce them with "intro patterns".

https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#intro-patterns

Here are small examples:

```ml
Lemma exple1 (A B : Prop) : A \/ B -> B \/ A.
Proof.
  (* disjunctive pattern *)
  intros [H | H'].
  - right; exact H.
  - left; exact H'.
Qed.

Lemma exple2 (A B : Prop) : A /\ B -> B /\ A.
Proof.
  (* conjunctive pattern *)
  intros [H H'].
  split.
  - exact H'.
  - exact H.
Qed.

Lemma exple3 (A B : Prop) : A /\ B -> A.
Proof.
  (* useless parts can be thrown away *)
  intros [H _].
  exact H.
Qed.

Lemma exple4 (A B C : Prop) : A /\ (B \/ C) -> (A /\ B) \/ (A /\ C).
Proof.
  (* intro patterns can be nested *)
  intros [HA [HB | HC]].
  - left. split.
    + exact HA.
    + exact HB.
  - right. split.
    + exact HA.
    + exact HC.
Qed.

Lemma exple5 (x : nat) : x = 0 -> x + x = x.
Proof.
  (* the -> intro pattern acts like "rewrite name; clear name" *)
  intros ->. reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma exple6 (x : nat) : x = 0 -> x = x + x.
Proof.
  (* the hyp%term intro pattern acts like "intros hyp; apply term in hyp" *)
  intros Hx%exple5. symmetry. exact Hx.
Qed.

Lemma exple6' (x : nat) : x = 0 -> x = x + x.
Proof.
  (* % intro patterns can be composed *)
  intros Hx%exple5%eq_sym. exact Hx.
Qed.

Lemma exple7 (A B : Prop) : A -> B -> A /\ B.
Proof.
  intros H1 H2.
  (* intro patterns can occur (almost) every time you name a term.
     assert ([H H']: A /\ B) fails but this works: *)
  assert (A /\ B) as [H H'].
  (* this was an artificial example *)
  easy. easy.
Qed.
```

About your original request,

```ml
assert (delta = 1 \/ delta <> 1) as [Hd | Hd] by lia.
```

does the trick, and you may want to consider :

```ml
assert (delta = 1 \/ delta <> 1) as [-> | Hd] by lia.
```

Comment: What does the notation `[-> | Hd]` mean?

Comment: This means : "in that case, instead of naming and introducing the equality `delta = 1`, use it to replace `delta` with `1` in the goal". Use the other arrow `<-` to rewrite in the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem to do that `Nat.eq_dec`. I usually import it by

```ml
Require Import Arith.
```

Then I do

```ml
destruct (Nat.eq_dec delta 1) as [Hd1|Hnd1].
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with natural numbers, you can also use booleans instead of properties. Using ssreflect, you could then do:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Lemma foo (delta : nat) : false.
Proof.
have [hd1|hd2] := boolP(delta == 1).
```

Comment: If `delta == 1` occurs in the context, you can use the shorter `case: eqP => [eq|neq].`. You can also do `case: @eqP _ delta 1 => [eq|neq].` even if it doesn't appear in the context, but then it's less obvious that it's better than Pierre's suggestion.